# Shorter One Liner with NumPy for grabbing indexes

Tags: numpy

I have the following line of code:

> ```
> idxs = [i for i,x in enumerate(labels) if x==lbl]
> ```

- labels is a numpy array of ints
- lbl is an int

idxs = indexes s.t. corresponding elements of labels has value lbl

Question: is there a shorter one-liner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the one-argument form of [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
idxs = np.where(labels == lbl)[0]
```

or, equivalently, use [numpy.nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
idxs = np.nonzero(labels == lbl)[0]
```

or, for better readability (thanks, Joe!),

```
idxs = np.flatnonzero(labels == lbl)
```

---

For example,

```
In [332]: np.random.seed(1)

In [333]: labels = np.random.randint(5, size=10)

In [334]: labels
Out[334]: array([3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 4, 4])

In [335]: [i for i,x in enumerate(labels) if x==lbl]
Out[335]: [3, 7]

In [336]: np.where(labels == lbl)[0]
Out[336]: array([3, 7])
```

---

Using `np.where` is much, much faster than the list comprehension for large arrays:

```
In [339]: labels = np.tile(labels, 1000)

In [340]: labels.shape
Out[340]: (10000,)

In [341]: %timeit np.where(labels == lbl)[0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.9 µs per loop

In [342]: %timeit [i for i,x in enumerate(labels) if x==lbl]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.31 ms per loop

In [343]: 5310/45.9
Out[343]: 115.68627450980392
```

Comment: apparently I need to wait 9 mins before accepting this answer

Comment: Just as a side note, there's also `np.flatnonzero(...)` which avoids the need for the `[0]`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the rep. to comment answers... Nevertheless, remember that when using `numpy.where` "lables" must be a numpy array.

Codelifting unutbu's answer:

`idxs = np.where(np.array(labels) == lbl)[0]`

Just to make it clear: the proper answer was made by unutbu.

Comment: Indeed, ended up using something similar -- np.asarray

Comment: PS: I would upvote your answer, but lack the rep to do so. :-)